# Can not create .p12 on mac?

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

I'm try to use apns service on ios,

but I can't export .p12 on my mac

(I can't open to see the key on left side of certificate)

I have no idea how to fix that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Q2F.png

I found that when I double-click the Certificates,

they always in Certificates not My Certificates,

so I cant found the private key,

anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: have you create csr and certificate from your machine and then submit?

Comment: I create csr from my mac,and upload that to my app Identifiers ->Push Notifications,and then download those and double click them to create the certificate

Comment: first of all add developer and distribution certificate hen after create push certificate and install

Answer (score 2):

In the side bar select "My Certificates" (fourth item from the top), then select the certificate, (not just the key).

Comment: I can't see any certificates in My Certificates,They just under Certificates(?,the sixth selection in the side bar

Comment: then may be in Certificates (last item). If there is none either, then you first have to create an certificate request to send to Apple, download the certificate and add it to keychain by double-clicking it. The global view "All Items" does not group certificate and key

Comment: I tried it 3 times,but still dont have private key...are there any solution to use apns if I can't create .p12 file?

Comment: in Keychain Access.app you need a view which groups certificate and key (disclosure triangle next to the certificate). There you are able to export .p12

Comment: please see my picture,I dont have any triangle/arrow ,I can't found my private key...I created that on other mac

Comment: you see no triangle because the view is "All Items". But without the private key you are not able to export the certificate anyway

Comment: I create csr from my mac,and upload that to my app Identifiers ->Push Notifications,and then download those and double click them to create the certificate,but none private key from my certificate

Comment: Again, try another view in Keychain Access.app to see the grouped Key / Certificates. Please double-check also the step by step description in the Apple documentation. If you successfully have created a CSR with "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" then you have a private key

Comment: I created the CSR with that,but I still don't have private key~I do that on other mac and never meet this problem...

Comment: @Louis after all the years, could you solve that problem? We have 2020 right now and I am running into same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that both of your public and private keys correspond to the identity that belongs to the certificate. I suggest deleting the certificates, and requesting new ones - this is what worked for me.

You will see a small dropdown arrow next the certificate you are trying to export when there are keys associated with it.

Comment: I try to make it again but still can't see the arrow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your default keychain is set to the keychain where the certificate is showing up without the .p12 export option. When you generate a .CSR to generate the cert the default keychain is used.

Set a keychain to default by right clicking it in the Keychain Access app and selecting 'Make Keychain "YouKeychainName" Default'